# Find 'net_rim_api.jar' version?

Tags: api, blackberry, version

Usually, Blackberry library comes with JDE named "net_rim_api.jar".

Now, the problem with how we come to know the API version ?

Let me explain to avoid digress viewers at all,

- suppose you just get "net_rim_api.jar" by somewhere/somehow
- Totally unaware about its relevant JDE

  Now, how you come to know the API version like 4.7 or .... ?

Cheers,
Amit.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, 'net_rim_api.jar' as any jar is an archive, so you extract the archive to a temp folder, open any .cod file from the root folder and look through with a HEX viewer. For instance, on my PC I have 2 JDEs (4.7 and 6.0), so I extract both jars, open 'net_rim_pdap_resources.cod' (just because it is the smallest .cod file) and (hurray!) I am able to observe the desired difference by these substrings:

- `6.0.0.141.net_rim_cldc.net_rim_pdap_resources`
- `4.7.0.75.net_rim_cldc.net_rim_pdap_resources`

Comment: Hello Arhimed, First of all thanks to you! Its seems by this way I'll overcome my anxiety but I tried it with HEX editor named "HHD Hex Editor Neo" but I didn't get the desire outcome. That's why could you please also suggest which HEX editor you are using (if any specific settings/steps required to customize it in order to view "4.7.0.75.net_rim_cldc.net_rim_pdap_resources" info then please also elaborate it).

Comment: @Amit Yadav: I believe this does not depend on which HEX editor/viewer to use. If this helps I used http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/

Comment: Thanks Arhimed, after your comments, I have been looked in (HEX view) cautiously and observed "4.99.0.12.net_rim_cldc.net_rim_pdap_resources". That’s really solved by anxiety.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project properties and then look at the Java Build Path. It should say in Libraries tab which version you are using.